# Query to include two additional column using SQL Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a requirement to create two additional Columns Capital and Interest from below three conditions

There are Three types of Transactions

- Payments
- Return
- Refund

Description : - Payment

1. If the Description type is **Payment** they  are posted in the Credit column  and the breakdown of this payment is having the below description which needs to covert this two-row into two-column under Payments row.

- Capital Credit Memo  - Capital Column
- Interest Credit Memo - Interest Column

### For Example :

| Id | Description | Postingdate | Valuedate | DebitAmount | CreditAmount | Expected Columns **Capital** | Expected Column **Interest** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6552 | Payment | 01/03/2022 | 26/02/2022 | 0 | 43.82 | 34.5 | 9.32 |
| 6552 | Interest Credit Memo | 01/03/2022 | 26/02/2022 | 0 | 9.32 |  |  |
| 6552 | Capital Credit Memo | 01/03/2022 | 26/02/2022 | 0 | 34.5 |  |  |

Same for Return

Similarly, if there are any Return  or Refund transactions it's posted in the Debit column  and the breakdown of this payment is split into Capital Debit  Memo & Interest Credit  Memo

Note the Posting date for Payment = Capital Credit Memo + Interest Credit same and also it will same for Return

### For Example :

| Id | Description | Postingdate | Valuedate | DebitAmount | CreditAmount | Expected Columns **Capital** | Expected Column **Interest** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6553 | Payment | 01/03/2022 | 26/02/2022 | 0 | 43.82 | 34.5 | 9.32 |
| 6553 | Interest Credit Memo | 01/03/2022 | 26/02/2022 | 0 | 9.32 |  |  |
| 6553 | Capital Credit Memo | 01/03/2022 | 26/02/2022 | 0 | 34.5 |  |  |
| 6553 | Return | 01/03/2022 | 26/02/2022 | 43.82 | NULL | 34.5 | 9.32 |
| 6553 | Interest Debit Memo | 01/03/2022 | 26/02/2022 | 9.32 | 0 |  |  |
| 6553 | Capital Debit Memo | 01/03/2022 | 26/02/2022 | 34.5 | 0 |  |  |
| 6552 | Payment | 01/03/2022 | 26/02/2022 | 0 | 43.82 | 34.5 | 9.32 |
| 6552 | Interest Credit Memo | 01/03/2022 | 26/02/2022 | 0 | 9.32 |  |  |
| 6552 | Capital Credit Memo | 01/03/2022 | 26/02/2022 | 0 | 34.5 |  |  |

Please could you advise how I can achieve this in SQL? below is my SQL Statement

````
select ft.ApplicationId,
tt.Description,
ft.PostingDate,
ft.ValueDate    ,
ft.DebitAmount  ,
ft.CreditAmount ,
from [dbo].[FinancialTransaction] as ft
left join TransactionType as TT on tt.TransactionTypeId=ft.TransactionTypeId
left join  [application] as a on a.ApplicationId =ft.ApplicationId
left join  [entity] as c on c.Entityid =a.CustomerEntityId```
````

Many Thanks in Advance

Comment: I think you are asking how to do a query that includes additional columns in the output.  This is not "creating" a column, since you are not creating any new objects in the database.

Comment: If that is what you are asking then you need to be clear what the rules are for those columns.  What exactly is the formula to get the Capital column -- what is the formula for the Interest column?  This is what you need to describe in your question.

Comment: Looks like you’re afte pivoting the data. Pivot or case expressions maybe with max is what you’re after

Comment: Could someone assist me with how do I  achieve this via Pivot or Case statement. Tried same
```CASE 
                WHEN tt.Description  = 'Capital Credit Memo'  THEN ft.CreditAmount
 WHEN tt.Description  = 'Capital Credit Memo' THEN ft.CreditAmount 
                    else null end as 'Capital' ```
But it's not working
The credit amount for  **Capital Credit Memo** is reflecting in the same row instead of **Payment** row

Answer (score 0):

> "convert this two-row into two-column under Payments row"

To reduce the number of rows, and increase the number of columns, with the new columns based on the value of another column, you need "conditional aggregation".

In essence this simply means placing a `case expression` inside an aggregate function such as `SUM()` e.g. `SUM(case when name='Fred' then col_value end) as sum_value`. So I imagine it will look something similar to this:

```
SELECT
      ft.ApplicationId
    , min(ft.PostingDate) AS min_postingDate
    , min(ft.ValueDate) AS min_valueDate
    , sum(CASE WHEN description = 'Payment ' THEN ft.CreditAmount END) AS CreditAmount
    , sum(CASE WHEN description = 'Capital Credit Memo' THEN ft.CreditAmount END) AS CapitalAmount
    , sum(CASE WHEN description = 'Interest Credit Memo' THEN ft.CreditAmount END) AS InterestAmount
FROM [dbo].[FinancialTransaction] AS ft
LEFT JOIN TransactionType AS TT ON tt.TransactionTypeId = ft.TransactionTypeId
LEFT JOIN [application] AS a ON a.ApplicationId = ft.ApplicationId
LEFT JOIN [entity] AS c ON c.Entityid = a.CustomerEntityId
GROUP BY
       ft.ApplicationId
```

Ii is very likely that I haven't got the case expressions correct, as one or more may need to use DebitAmount, and there may be more then one value of description to be included e.g.

```
    , sum(CASE WHEN description IN ('Payment','Return') THEN ft.CreditAmount END) AS CreditAmount
```

Hopefully this is enough for you to implement the wanted logic.